# Vue update state

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have problems updating state with Vue. It's really simple problem so I will not post full code, because there is a lot of it.
So the problem is that I'm updating some data with websockets, and until now everything worked fine, but now, when I tried to get this data as a state, it's not updating realtime.
For example, I have a form that looks like this:

```
    props: ['order'],
    data() {
        return {
            client_form: {
                order_id: this.$route.params.id,
                client_id: this.order.client.id,
                fullName: this.order.client.fullName,
                email: this.order.client.email,
                phone: this.order.client.phone,
                city: this.order.client.shipping.city,
                address: this.order.client.shipping.address,
                zip: this.order.client.shipping.zip,
                province: this.order.client.shipping.province,
                comment: this.order.comment
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm getting props order, and It's updating from parent component.
So, if I call for example `{{ order.client.fullName }}` in template, it will update it realtime, but when I try with `{{ fullName }}` it's not updating.

What should I do to update this states?

Answer (score 1):

define `client_form` as computed property in order to watch route and props changes and returns the new values :

```
 props: ['order'],
 computed:{
    client_form() {
        return {
                order_id: this.$route.params.id,
                client_id: this.order.client.id,
                fullName: this.order.client.fullName,
                email: this.order.client.email,
                phone: this.order.client.phone,
                city: this.order.client.shipping.city,
                address: this.order.client.shipping.address,
                zip: this.order.client.shipping.zip,
                province: this.order.client.shipping.province,
                comment: this.order.comment
            }
        }
}
```

then in template do : `{{client_form.fullName}}`

Comment: Work as charm :D

Comment: please don't forget to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)